# Staging an individual hunk using PyGit2

Tags: git, libgit2, pygit2

I'm trying to implement `git add -p` in pygit2, so I can make an alternative frontend to it. So I need to be able to stage individual hunks, first and foremost.

I'm able to find the hunks by using `diff_to_workdir` from the index, like this:

```
index.diff_to_workdir(0,1,1)[0].hunks
```

But I'm not sure exactly how to proceed from there. In fact, my intuition tells me that I don't stage things at all, but rather put together a commit myself and then hand it to the repo.

I have the sense that I ultimately need to be able to create a blob from the hunk and then use TreeBuilder to create a commit. But I just can't get there! It seems like I can only create blobs from files. Can anyone give a little guidance?

Answer (score 1):

In order to stage files, there is no need to get anywhere close to a commit, or even a tree. All you need is to put the new version of the file in the on-disk index.

First you get the current version of the file in the index

```
path = 'src/somefile.py'
repo = Repository('.')
index = Repository.index
id = index[path].id
contents = repo[id].data
```

Once you've applied the diff to the staged version of the file, you can write those patched contents to the object db and create tree new  index entry with

```
new_contents = my_favourite_patch_lib.patch(contents, hunk)
new_id = repo.write(new_contents, GIT_OBJ_BLOB)
new_entry = IndexEntry(path, new_id, GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB)
```

and now you can update the index and write it out to disk so the rest of the system can pick it up

```
index.add(new_entry)
index.write()
```

Now you have the new contents of the file available in the repository and the index considers these new contents to be the state of the file.

Comment: So it seems like I'm responsible for making a diff out of the hunk(s) that I want to stage and then applying that diff to the file in the repo? Is there anything in pygit2 that lets you make diffs out of hunks?

Comment: libgit2 has convenience functions to format patches for you, if you want more control over them, you'd have to use your own print functions.